# Set wait_timout to 30 ,still sleep connections are increasing with a constant rate

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, connection-pooling, bitnami

[RESOLVED]

IT SEEMS PHP MYADMIN VARIABLES DID THE TRICK.
I SET wait_timeout to 30   , and  Lock_wait_timeout to 50
Took almost 6 hours to get back to stable,including several restarts,may be time needs to read those changes.

PROBLEM :

Site Address http://topyaps.com

Num of queries on homepage `322 in 2 seconds`

Nothing in Slow query log file.

I am using `BITNAMI LAMP SERVER[amazon ec2]` to run my wordpress based heavy site.

Problem is,my server crashes every 10 minutes.

Reason,as i guess, 
when i check processlist using putty,it seems to be increasing constantly at very high rate ,all specifies `sleep` command.

I tried setting variables like :

```
wait_timeout=30
interactive_timeout=30
connect_timeout=15
max_user_connections=25
max_connections=999
```

but it doesn't seem to do any help.

LINK TO  THE  PICTURE OF PHPMYADMIN MONITOR,FOR A SINGLE PAGE LOAD[homepage]: http://postimg.org/image/5qqgb30xb/

HERE IS WHAT I GOT FROM PHPMYADMIN STATUS:

```
Questions since startup: 50,617 Documentation
ø per hour: 138,361
ø per minute: 2,306
ø per second: 38

Statements  #   ø per hour  %
select  46,128  126.1 k 91.13
set option  2,452   6,702.5 4.84
change db   1,226   3,351.3 2.42
update  516 1,410.5 1.02
insert  135 369 0.27
delete  116 317.1   0.23
show binlogs    13  35.5    0.03
show variables  5   13.7    0.01
show processlist    5   13.7    0.01
show master status  4   10.9    0.01
show slave status   4   10.9    0.01
show databases  4   10.9    0.01
show tables 3   8.2 0.01
show status 3   8.2 0.01
show grants 1   2.7  <0.01
kill    1   2.7  <0.01
show table status   1   2.7  <0.01
select
set option
change db
update
insert
delete
show binlogs
Other
91%5%
```

I checked out my page queries it shows "328 queries in 2 seconds".

How to actually stop these connections ???

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to see what these queries are first. Why are you having that many. If they are all repetitive queries and they are called on every connection, I would consider caching. You can install [memcached](http://memcached.org/) and a plugin like [W3TotalCache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) to cache your database queries. You can also cache frontend using W3TotalCache.
Memcached is a key-value store that stores the result of queries in the memory. So your database does not get hits on the same queries every time.
Also if you are using innodb as the storage engine, change the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 60% of your RAM

Comment: can you help me,in how to check which query is not running or which query is slow??I am using ssh client putty.

Comment: the easiest way is to install phpmyadmin and see their monitoring section and the slow query log

Comment: hello,i updated few things,with picture.My lock wait_timeout is  31,536,000   is it something different from wait_timeout?

Comment: can you get a query log?

Comment: i got one slow query that's it.may i know how to get complete set of queries with execution time and sleeping connections..like where these connections are coming from

Comment: do you have memcached installed? on the other note I see you have master/slave can you make sure reads are not going to the master?

Comment: well,i am really sorry but i have no idea how to check that.

Comment: on replication i can see Master replication This server is not configured as master in a replication process. Would you like to configure it? Slave replication This server is not configured as slave in a replication process. Would you like to configure it?

Comment: ok don't touch that. go to your server and install memcached then install w3totalcache google for instructions

Comment: Hello,i have installed memcache on my apache and in my.ini file i have enabled it....may i know how to use it??

Comment: Now install w3totalcache on your wordpress then under database cache choose memcach and save

Comment: Ahh as soon as i enable wp super cache or w3totalcache,my site gets blank.I deactivated supercache before installing w3totalcache///  one more thing is it says The following memcached servers are not responding or not running:

Database Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.

Comment: chat doesn't work here for some reason. but this is when memcached is not running.

Comment: I checked memcached and other requirements of plugin and it itself confirmed ok status for every requirement.Infact my wp admin is working fine,just the front-end..Yes you are right...chat will never help..Its actually great when people as expertise as you,show their help...One last out of the box question..m a php developer with 8 months of experience...how would you suggest me to learn things to get a better job?

Comment: At this point I'd suggest moving a copy of everything to another server configuring caching then point people to that server terminating this one. Read books, documentation and play around with things on your own good luck

Answer (score 0):

Although I can barely access yout site, the query to page ratio seems very high for a common wordpress install. My best guess is that you have too many plugins which in turn run too many custom queries on each page load.

You need to identify the source of this queries and find a way to offload them to a cache mechanism such as memcache. There are some caching plugins such as W3TC that offer to do this for you, but in the case of custom tailored queries it might not be too effective.

You say you're running on a bitnami lamp configuration, so your mysql runs in the same machine as your webserver. Have you considered running a separate mysql server, such as Amazon RDS? This won't be a magical solution, but will allow you to better diagnose the bottleneck while at the same time stopping you from tampering with mysql configuration, which is rarely the way to go.

What DNS are you using? I've found out that using [Cloudflare's](http://www.cloudflare.com) free dns service does provide a basic caching layer for static files, so user might be served a static copy of your html when they hit the frontpage. You'd have to configure cloudflare to perform an aggresive html caching. But as I said, it's free and it helps.

Comment: Yes it again got crashed,so thats why u failed to open it.

Comment: Quite a strange thing,but when i enable wp super cache,my whole site becomes a blank page.

Comment: on replication  i can see   Master replication
This server is not configured as master in a replication process. Would you like to configure it?
Slave replication
This server is not configured as slave in a replication process. Would you like to configure it?